# Android: Obtain the int value of a preference key

Tags: android, key, listener, switch-statement, sharedpreferences

I'd like to add an OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener and to do a switch based on the key that is passed into

```
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
switch(obtainIntFromKey(key)){
    case R.string.settings_some_propery : doSomething(); break;
    ...
}
```

How does the `obtainIntFromKey(key)` method has to look like?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in current method:

```
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
    int value = sharedPreferences.getInt(key, 0);
    switch(value){
    case R.string.settings_some_propery : doSomething(); break;
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Hm, this just crashed in the emulator and on the phone:


    `FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Boolean
 at android.app.ContextImpl$SharedPreferencesImpl.getInt(ContextImpl.java:3057)
 at com.myapp.services.SchedulerService$1.onSharedPreferenceChanged(SchedulerService.java:174)
 at android.app.ContextImpl$SharedPreferencesImpl$EditorImpl.notifyListeners(ContextImpl.java:3270)
 at android.app.ContextImpl$SharedPreferencesImpl...`


Since it don't seem to have access to this specific line of source code, I cannot tell what's the root cause...

Comment: I believe this is not exactly what I wanted. What this method ought to return is the int value that this preference should have (an instance so to say) while I was looking for the int value that is used to encode that string in the R file... Please correct me if I am drawing the wrong conclusions...

Answer (score 0):

What you are wanting to switch by is incorrect. OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener will pass the resolved key literal. Unfortunately, you can't use switch()..case statement with the key it is passing (unless you are on [Java 7](http://java.dzone.com/articles/new-java-7-feature-string)). Since your preference screen has limited options and you know beforehand what they are, you check for those keys that you want to react to when changed:

```
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key){
    if(key.equals(getString(R.string.somestringresourceyoucareabout)) {
       //if you ask the user to enter an int value for this key then you need to cast it explicitly since preferences will store everything as text except for checkboxpreference
       int value = Integer.parseInt(prefs.getString(key, defaultValue));
    }
    else if(key.equals(getString(...)) {
       ...
    } 
}
```

**You may want to research on working with Java 7 with the eclipse ADT plugin if you really want to use the switch()..case.** Frankly, if you are writing a case statement for each of the keys you wish to reach to, you can use nested if..else if conditions instead and be done with it instead of spending time getting to use Java 7 with ADT.